# Extract numbers from a string in Informix

Tags: sql, informix

There are strings in my table as follows:

```
select '1. name 1' from dual union all
select '2. name 2' from dual union all
select '11. name 3' from dual union all
select '12. name 4' from dual
```

I need to extract the first numbers:

> 1 2 11 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IBM [claims](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_2337.htm) that Informix supports `substring_index()`.  If so:

```
select substring_index(col, '.', 1)
```

This doesn't exactly get the first *number*.  It returns the first part of the string before the `'.'`, which appears to be the same thing.

Comment: substring_index() supported by informix 11?

Comment: @dmitriy it's supported since v11.70.xC3.